# Can't view certain PDF documents on galaxy s7 Marshmallow 6.0.1

Tags: 6.0-marshmallow, pdf

There are certain pdf files I cannot view on my phone no matter what pdf viewer I use. I'll get an error message saying that it's an invalid document (the message varies slightly from application to application) even though it's a pdf. I can view these files on my desktop and on an older phone I have. There are some pdf files I CAN view on my current phone, but I don't know what is different about those.

Why can't I view these files on my phone? How can I view these files on my phone?

Comment: Have you tried the official Adobe app?

Comment: Yeah, that's what I was using by default. I don't know what was causing it, but I cleared all of my default applications and it seems to be working now

Comment: even i am facing this issue.

Comment: @user3162859 Glad you were able to solve your issue! You could [answer your own question](http://android.stackexchange.com/help/self-answer) and then later accept your own answer; that would help people with a similar issue to identify your post as solution.